# reading from stdin - 32-bit vs 64-bit

Tags: c, 64-bit

I have a program which I am compiling ok on both 32 and 64-bit. But when I run the 64-bit version, my results are wrong.  Trying to read input from stdin using fread results in reading 0x400 less in 64-bit than in 32-bit.  Is it because the buffer allocated using malloc isn't big enough?

```
.....
static char *buffer;
int size;
.....
buffer = malloc(size);

if ((fread(buffer, 1, size, in) != size)
   fprintf(stderr, "not read completely\n");
else 
   fprintf(stderr, "input completely read\n");
.....
```

Comment: Did you compile with `gcc -Wall` ? Did you get any warnings ? Did you fix them ?

Comment: Do you include `<stdio.h>`? Third and second arguments of `fread()` are `size_t` that size depends on platform, and if compiler don't have it's prototype, it will get two `int`s.

Comment: Yes I have included the header .. -Wall warnings that I fixed didn't help.

Comment: I think we need an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) now.

Comment: besides the MCVE, also include a usable sample of what is being read.

Comment: Be sure to use `size_t size;` and check results of `malloc()`.

Comment: Hmmmm: curious to read from `stdin` (usually a text stream) with `fread()` (best with binary streams).   Please show evidence that "reading 0x400 less" is in fact wrong.  There is just not enough code and data here to pin point the issue.

Comment: Try viva64 tool: http://www.viva64.com/en/viva64-tool/

Comment: Thanks everyone .. in the process of writing the MCVE, I realized that I was reading more than I should have in the previous read (because in the 64-bit case the size was different - which was the bug) and that resulted in getting 1024 bytes less.  Thanks again for the help.